# Name for a kind of topological property?

Tags: gn.general-topology, at.algebraic-topology

What should I call a property (P) of (open) subspaces of a space $X$ such that:

1. If  $U$  satisfies (P), then so does every open subset $V\subset U$
2. If {$U_i$} is a pairwise disjoint collection of sets satisfying (P), then 
   $\bigcup_i U_i$ satisfies (P).  (Unable to make braces?)

My understanding is that if (P) satisfies condition 1, then (P) is called a
hereditary property.

CLARIFICATION:  My main question is really:  is there existing terminology for such 
a property?

I will, however be happy to consider suggestions on the secondary question: if not, then what should I call it?

Comment: I would say that *hereditary* is generally reserved for properties which are inherited by *all* subspaces, not just open ones. To be honest, I would not introduce a name for such a thing, but only a shorthand («Let us, for briefness, call *excellent* a property such that ... and ...», and then talk about «excellent properties»; if the concept catches up, this makes it more probable that you get immortalized with «Stromian property» or something!)

Comment: Rather than using pedestrian adjectives like _excellent_ or _good_ (unless you are really trying to get it named after you), it maybe better to make a definition to the effect that a property (P) satisfying conditions (1) and (2) are said to be in class S. 

Comment: I find adjectives more readable. Compare "Take a good property and assume..." with "Take a property of class S and assume..."

Comment: Why not "disjoint-communicative"? (after the affine communication lemma in Ravi Vakil's notes)

Comment: I should have said this before: if you are going to pick an adjective, please oh please let it be not «admissible»!

Comment: @Mariano.  I was thinking of "regular."

Comment: "Class S" is extra nice since your name starts with S.  Hey, it worked for Banach.

Comment: Don't know about Banach, but it sure worked for Tate!

Answer (score 3):

I would call such a property  *hereditary and (completely) additive on open sets*. If you want to specify a cardinality constraint on the index set I, then adverbs like finitely/countably (or sigma) may be useful.